# Impedance matching for broad bandwidth voltage amplifier

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, impedance, photodiode

I need some basic advice for impedance matching: I have a photodetector (Det01CFC from Thorlabs) that generates a current. For my experiment, I would like to amplify this signal with an amplifier. The amplifier that I can use is the LNA-1440 with an input impedance of 50 Ohm.

What kind of circuit would you use to get the best performance in terms of bandwidth and gain? For example, would it work to connect the photodetector directly to the amplifier since they seem to have a matching impedance, or do I need something in between?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: A data sheet link to the ThorLabs device is needed.

Comment: What frequency band do you need to measure?

Comment: The datasheet for the photodetector is: https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/275cb418cdc2cf1f-A2E46103-D9C0-3581-4553E3D3CA93AD83/DET01CFC-Manual.pdf, The datasheet for the amplifier is: https://rfbayinc.com/products_pdf/product_88.pdf

Comment: I plan to measure from about 5 MHz to 100 MHz

Comment: It seems as though they should work fine when connected. Make sure your amplifier has a 50 ohm input impedance (the data sheet appears to say it does).

Comment: Could it make sense to add a t-piece with a 50 Ohm termination between the photodetector and the amplifier?

Comment: @SandroCamenzind, no, that would be loading the detector with 25 ohms (50 ohm amplifier in parallel with 50 ohm termination) instead of the 50 ohms it is designed for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the manual for your detector:

[image]

This detector is designed to drive a 50-ohm load. Since your amplifier has a 50-ohm input, there is no matching network required. You can just connect the detector to the amplifier through a 50-ohm cable.

In comments you added,

> I plan to measure from about 5 MHz to 100 MHz

You should probably include a 100-150 MHz low pass filter in your system to eliminate noise that your 1.2 GHz detector and 1.4 GHz amplifier will be producing outside your signal band.

Comment: I saw this, but as I am new to electronic circuits I wanted to make sure that I get it right. Thank you very much for your help and for the valuable hint with the low pass filters!